# C# calculate total weights

Tags: c#, calculation

I have two classes as below. I get products list 'ProductBooleans' along with the category flag if they fit in it. I also get the weight for each category 'ProductWeight. I need to find the the total weight for each category.

```
public class ProductBooleans
{
    public int Prodid;
    public int Cat1;
    public int Cat2;
    public int Cat3;
}

public class ProductWeight
{
    public string Cat;
    public int Wt;
}
```

I need to calculate the total weight for each product in the basket and return the dict<int,int>

```
ProductBoolean

var pbs = new List<ProductBooleans>()
{
    new ProductBooleans() { Prodid = 333, Cat1 = 1, Cat2 = 0, Cat3 = 1, },
    new ProductBooleans() { Prodid = 444, Cat1 = 1, Cat2 = 1, Cat3 = 0, },
};

ProductWeight

var pws = new List<ProductWeight>()
{
    new ProductWeight() { Cat = "Cat1", Wt = 10, },
    new ProductWeight() { Cat = "Cat2", Wt = 20, },
    new ProductWeight() { Cat = "Cat3", Wt = 30, },
};
```

Result should be

```
Prodid | totalWt
333        40
444        30
```

*NOTE: I am currently using reflection to solve this problem but I think there has to be much simpler way to achieve this.*
Is there lib to do this or a simpler way?

Comment: Will there be different class that led you to use reflection in the first place? Seems to be doable with Linq as long as the class stays that way.

Comment: Please update your post: Q: Where are you reading the data from?  A text file?  Q: Can you show us some code?  PS: I can't imagine how - or why - you're using "reflection".  I'm hoping your code might help clarify...

Comment: @paulsm4 - I am reading from db. something like this matchingCriteria.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName).GetValue(matchingCriteria, null);

Answer (score 0):

This seems to do the job for me:

```
var query =
    from pb in pbs
    let totalWt =
    (
        from x in new (string Cat, int Wt)[]
        {
            ("Cat1", pb.Cat1),
            ("Cat2", pb.Cat2),
            ("Cat3", pb.Cat3),
        }
        join pw in pws on x.Cat equals pw.Cat
        select x.Wt * pw.Wt
    ).Sum()
    select new
    {
        pb.Prodid,
        totalWt
    };
```

That gives me:

[image: result]

---

Here's a version that uses reflection:

```
(string Cat, int Wt)[] GetValues(ProductBooleans pb) =>
    typeof(ProductBooleans)
        .GetFields()
        .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith("Cat"))
        .Where(p => p.FieldType == typeof(int))
        .Select(p => (p.Name, (int)p.GetValue(pbs[0])))
        .ToArray();

var query =
    from pb in pbs
    let totalWt =
    (
        from x in GetValues(pb)
        join pw in pws on x.Cat equals pw.Cat
        select x.Wt * pw.Wt
    ).Sum()
    select new
    {
        pb.Prodid,
        totalWt
    };
```

Obviously change `.GetFields()` to `.GetProperties()` if that's needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The total categories can vary...so I need to have generic way of doing it.

Comment: @user3906850 - You need to include that salient point in your question.

Comment: @user3906850 - I've added an answer that uses reflection. I'd be interested in why you have an object model that you need to use reflection with.

Comment: I dont want to use reflection actually. I calculate my product's matching criteria in code and I have weights for each criteria in db (WeightRules table). I can have a different set of weights for different strategies and each product will calculate the weight as per the WeightRules.

Comment: @user3906850 - Your question is quickly becoming more and more irrelevant to your actual needs. You need to make sure what you ask is what you need. Can you please provide clear and detailed examples of "calculate my product's matching criteria" and "different set of weights for different strategies and each product will calculate the weight as per the WeightRules"?

Answer (score -1):

```
        var _categoryDic = new Dictionary<Category, bool>();
        _categoryDic.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate1", CatId = 1 }, true);
        _categoryDic.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate2", CatId = 2 }, false);
        _categoryDic.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate3", CatId = 3 }, true);
        productBooleans.Add(new ProductBooleans()
        {
            prodid = 333
                        ,
            categoryDic = _categoryDic
        });

        var _categoryDic2 = new Dictionary<Category, bool>();
        _categoryDic2.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate1", CatId = 1 }, true);
        _categoryDic2.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate2", CatId = 2 }, true);
        _categoryDic2.Add(new Category() { CategoryName = "cate3", CatId = 3 }, false);
        productBooleans.Add(new ProductBooleans()
        {
            prodid = 444
                        ,
            categoryDic = _categoryDic2
        });

        List<ProductWeight> productWeights = new List<ProductWeight>();

        productWeights.Add(new ProductWeight() { category = new Category() { CategoryName = "cate1", CatId = 1 }, weight = 10 });
        productWeights.Add(new ProductWeight() { category = new Category() { CategoryName = "cate2", CatId = 2 }, weight = 20 });
        productWeights.Add(new ProductWeight() { category = new Category() { CategoryName = "cate3", CatId = 3 }, weight = 30 });

        var _prodBool =productBooleans.Select(i => new {
                                                                    prod_id = i.prodid
                                                                     ,
            categoryList = i.categoryDic
                            .Where(j => j.Value)
                            .Select(j => j.Key)
                            .ToList<Category>()
        }).ToList();
        Dictionary<int, int> resultList=new Dictionary<int, int>();
        foreach (var item in _prodBool)
        {
            int itemweight = 0;
            foreach (var pw in productWeights)
            {
                itemweight += (item.categoryList.Where(i => i.CatId == pw.category.CatId).Any()) ? pw.weight : 0;
            }
            resultList.Add(item.prod_id, itemweight);
        }
        return resultList;
```

Comment: Why did you change the class definitions and not post them with your code? How can we test this?